# Is there an A/B testing feature in GA4?

Tags: google-optimize

On the [Google Optimize sunset](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/12979939?sjid=2168464655406883285-EU) announcement, there's this statement...

> We remain committed to enabling businesses of all sizes to improve your user experiences and are investing in third-party A/B testing integrations for Google Analytics 4.

I've had a good look around GA4, and can't see any hint of an A/B testing feature.

> We are focused on bringing the most effective solutions and integrations to our customers, especially as we look toward the future with Google Analytics 4.

Does this mean that there is no A/B testing *yet* and there will be in the future, or am I misreading the statement from Google? Is there a beta that I'm not seeing?

Or, are they just referring to things like Firebase A/B Testing?

> **What will happen to Firebase A/B Testing?**
>
> [Firebase A/B Testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing) helps
> you optimize your app experiences by making it easy to run, analyze,
> and scale product and marketing experiments. While we acknowledge that
> Firebase uses the Google Optimize infrastructure for inference
> computation, Google is committed to continuing to support and evolve
> Firebase A/B Testing in the future. Firebase A/B Testing will not be
> impacted by the Google Optimize sunset.

Answer (score 4):

It's my interperteation that since sunsetting Google Optmize, there will be no native A/B testing platform within Google Analytics 4.

If you wish to A/B test, they will provide integration with the [following providers](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/12979939?hl=en#:%7E:text=What%20will%20testing%20in%20Google%20Analytics%20look%20like%20moving%20forward%3F). Once integrated, an audience will be created and you can **analyze** the results within Google Analytics.

You can see more information under the [How it Works](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/12979533?sjid=16043892515064125965-AP#:%7E:text=determine%20a%20winner.-,How%20it%20works,-When%20you%20create) section in this support article.